# Построить график и вывести в Qt

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5

Написал программу на Python используя Qt, ни как не могу разобраться, как правильно построить график и вывести его в окне Qt, в интернете перерыл кучу вариантов и способов, но как-то всё вокруг да около двигаюсь...

Хотелось бы чтобы окно с графиком выглядело примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные для графика беру из заранее известного словаря и при открытии окна с графиком туда будет передаваться данный словарь, пример:
{'Январь 2018': -30, 'Февраль 2018': -10, 'Март 2018': 10, ...}

Из кода на данный момент есть:

```
# Файл 1
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class FGraph(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1089, 689)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 1041, 521))
    self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
    self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 0, 801, 41))
    self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
    self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 50, 491, 20))
    self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 610, 111, 16))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 610, 551, 20))
    self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(884, 640, 171, 20))
    self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Текст"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Текст "))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "За период с ... по ..."))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Time"))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Текст"))
    self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Date"))

# Файл 2
from Qt_ReportAIST_graph import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget


class WGraph(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
       self.report = FGraph()
       self.report.setupUi(self)

# Файл 3 Не обязательно использовать для графика pylab
import pylab
xlist = ["Январь 2018", "Февраль 2018", "Март 2018", "Апрель 2018", "Май 2018", "Июнь 2018", "Июль 2018", "Август 2018", "Сентябрь 2018", "Октябрь 2018", "Ноябрь 2018", "Декабрь 2018"]
ylist = [-30, -10, 10, 100, 80, 60, 40, 99, 3, 10, 15, 37]
pylab.plot(xlist, ylist)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: У qt есть qchart: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#details . Либо вы можете другой библиотекой сгенерировать график в картинку и отобразить на QLabel, к примеру

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [pyqtgraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/). Библиотека предоставляет удобные виджеты для вывода графиков почти любого вида. Написана на Qt, поэтому работает очень быстро и очень просто встраивается в приложение на PyQt. Вот простой пример:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np


class Window(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.view = view = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.curve = view.plot(name="Line")

        self.btn = Qt.QPushButton("Random plot")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.random_plot)

        layout.addWidget(Qt.QLabel("Some text"))
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

    def random_plot(self):
        random_array = np.random.random_sample(20)
        self.curve.setData(random_array)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Понемногу начал вникать) Только пока не могу найти варианта, как по оси X вывести массив и отобразить вертикально xlist = ["Январь 2018", "Февраль 2018", "Март 2018", "Апрель 2018", "Май 2018", "Июнь 2018", "Июль 2018", "Август 2018", "Сентябрь 2018", "Октябрь 2018", "Ноябрь 2018", "Декабрь 2018"]
 Только с цифрами работает.

Comment: Вот здесь пример того как сделать: https://gist.github.com/friendzis/4e98ebe2cf29c0c2c232

Comment: Большое спасибо!